# Manipulating object data in event handlers

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling

For a final project, I am making a WPF application that keeps track of Dungeons and Dragons combat statistics.

Every instance of the application has a Session object that keeps track of the turns. I need to be able to increment the turn variable in Session when the "Next Turn" button is pressed.

Here is my C# code.

```
namespace CombatTracker
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Session CurrentSession = new Session();
        }

        //creates new session
        private void btnNewSession_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow NewSession = new MainWindow();
            NewSession.Show();
            Close();
        }

        //increments the turn count 
        private void btnNextTurn_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //???????????
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Session class.

```
namespace CombatTracker
{
    public class Session
    {
        private int turn = 1;

        public int nextTurn()
        {
            return turn++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for [Static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) variables.

Comment: To add to what S.Akbari was saying, a static variable belongs to a class, not an instance of the class. So if you change a static variable in one instance of a class, it changes it for every instance of that class. Any method that modifies a static variable will also need to be static itself.

Comment: You have `CurrentSession` declared in `MainWindow` constructor. If you want to change `turn` value of it in `btnNextTurn_Button_Click` then you should declare `CurrentSession` at the class level.